# django custom management command does not show up in production

Tags: django

I wrote a [custom management](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/) command for django. Locally with my dev settings everything works fine. Now I deployed my project onto the production server and the management command does not show up, respectively is not available. But I did not get an error message deploying the project (syncdb).

Any ideas where I could try to begin to search?
Is there a special command that all custom management commands are "autodiscovered"?

--Edit--

Solved and documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527329/django-custom-management-commands-from-admin-interface/4532480#4532480)

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas for you:

- The `settings.py` or `local_settings.py` file is different on the production server and doesn't initialize the app with your custom command.
- It has something to do with `DEBUG` being enabled/disabled.  Do you have some type of variable setting somewhere that would affect that?

Comment: both settings.py initialize the corresponding app. In production I set DEBUG and TEMPLATE_DEBUG to FALSE whereas in dev. it is set to TRUE. But this should not affect the management commands. thanks for your reply! hmm... strange..